# Python: lxml.etree.tostring(with_comments=False)

Tags: python, xml, xml-serialization

I call the following command and get the following error:

```
>>>lxml.etree.tostring([tree].getroot(), with_comments=False)
ValueError: Can only discard comments in C14N serialisation
```

I don't know what C14N is, but I would appreciate an explanation of how I can achieve it and  run the foregoing command with `with_comments=False`.  (Yes, I'm aware that I can strip the comments using regex. Please don't offer regular expressions as a solution.)

**Background:** I want to transfer my xml doc over an http connection.  I'm using the lxml Python library.  I'm running on Python 2.7.1

Comment: what version of lxml is this? isn't it etree.tostring() not to_string()

Comment: "C14N" is short for "Canonicalization" — it refers to the canonical XML serialization: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n

Comment: Right, it is `tostring()`.  (I got it right in the title, though).  I couldn't say what version of lxml (but I assume that the question was inspired because I had written the method name incorrectly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [lxml.etree.tostring](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring) doc says:

> The exclusive and with_comments arguments are only used with C14N output, where they request exclusive and uncommented C14N serialisation respectively.

That parameter is only valid when using `method='c14n'`. You can omit it, and as far as I know, it will not include comments. Even if it did, the xml parser on the receiving end should ignore them, so unless there's a bandwidth concern or you have a specific problem with it, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 9):

You can remove the comments at parsing time:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True)
tree = etree.parse(xmlfile, parser=parser)
```

Or when using objectify (took me hell of a time to find this out):

```
parser = objectify.makeparser(remove_comments=True)
tree = objectify.parse(xmlfile, parser=parser)
```