# How to not load the comments while parsing XML in lxml

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, comments, lxml

I try to parse XML file in Python using lxml like this:

```
objectify.parse(xmlPath, parserWithSchema)
```

but XML file may contains comments in strange places:

```
<root>
    <text>Sam<!--comment-->ple text</text>
    <!--comment-->
    <float>1.2<!--comment-->3456</float>
</root>
```

It is a way to not load or delete comments before parsing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set `remove_comments=True` on the parser ([documentation](http://lxml.de/parsing.html)):

```
from lxml import etree, objectify

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True)
tree = objectify.parse(xmlPath, parser=parser)
```

Or, using the `makeparser()` method:

```
parser = objectify.makeparser(remove_comments=True)
tree = objectify.parse(xmlPath, parser=parser)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This did not work for me. The correct way was to use `parser = objectify.makeparser(remove_comments=True)` as indicated here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7513498/551045

Comment: @RedX thank you, I've improved the answer accordingly.