# Parsing XML lxml should I skip or remove comment blocking parsing

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an XML file which first line begins with

```
<!--
```

Is there a way for lxml to skip this line and treat line 2 as the 1st line or should I remove it before handing to lxml?

for example I tried implementing the example from the lxml documentation

```
>>> root = etree.XML("<root><a>TEXT</a></root>")

>>> find_text = etree.XPath("//text()")
>>> text = find_text(root)[0]
>>> print(text)
TEXT
```

and because of the first line I receive this error.

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

this is my script I am using to run the file

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml import objectify
import argparse
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("path", type=str, nargs="+")
parser.add_argument('-e',
                    '--extension',
                    default='',
                    help='File extension to filter by.')

args = parser.parse_args()
name_pattern = "*" + args.extension
my_dir = args.path[0]

for dir_path, subdir_list, file_list in os.walk(my_dir):
    for name_pattern in file_list:
        full_path = os.path.join(dir_path, name_pattern)
        # print(full_path)
        # print(file_list)


def getsMeet(file_list):
    for filename in sorted(file_list):
        filename=my_dir + filename
        yield filename

def parseXML():
    """
    from mouse parsing a file with objectify
    http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/06/parsing-xml-with-python-using-lxml-objectify/
    """
    for file in getsMeet(file_list):
        with open(file) as f:
            xml = f.read()

            root = objectify.fromstring(xml)
            print(root.tag)
            # print(objectify.dump(root))
            race = objectify.Element("race")
            print(objectify.dump(race))


parseXML()
```

The file is valid doing dump root with Objectify works perfectly, it was etree that failed.

This is the comment and a selected snip of the first element of XML a rather large file.

```
<!-- Copyright Notice: © 2010 Racing NSW (and other parties working with it). NSW racing information,including fields, form and results, is subject to copyright which is owned by Racing NSW and other parties working with it. -->
<meeting id="42977" barriertrial="0" venue="Rosehill Gardens" date="2016-05-21T00:00:00" gearchanges="-1" stewardsreport="-1" gearlist="-1" racebook="0" postracestewards="0" meetingtype="TAB" rail="Timing - Electronic : Rail - +6m" weather="Fine      " trackcondition="Good 3    " nomsdeadline="2016-05-16T11:00:00" weightsdeadline="2016-05-17T16:00:00" acceptdeadline="2016-05-18T09:00:00" jockeydeadline="2016-05-18T12:00:00">
</meeting>
```

Comment: `<!--` is a comment tag, you can either ignore it or delete it programmatically (but remember to get rid of enclosing tag too!). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18313932/5922757) you can see how to skip comments in XML with lxml. Is the whole XML file commented out? Because in your example I can't see any comments tags as you said is the case with your file.

Comment: comment node in front of the document element tag should have been recognized properly by xml parsers... that might be a bug in lxml...

Comment: Can you include the code you are using to load your file, and can you include a few more lines from the XML file itself?

Comment: Do you know for sure that your xml is valid?  A properly closed comment should not be a problem.  Check out http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment should really cause no issues with *etree* and does not on my machine using python2 or python3, if you do want to remove comments though you can pass `parser=et.HTMLParser(remove_comments=True)` or `parser=et.XMLParser(remove_comments=True))` depending on what you want:

```
import  lxml.etree as et

x = et.parse("test.xml", parser=et.HTMLParser(remove_comments=True))
print(et.tostring(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Kill the copyright notice.  You have an extended ascii character (the copyright symbol) in an xml document without encoding specified, without an xml declaration tag, in a python 3 unicode environment.  I can't imagine good things happening.  Remove the copyright symbol and see of your problems go away.

Comment: While I agree with this sentiment and advice, it's not really an answer to the question and would be better communicated as a comment.